# Reverse and repeat String words in java

Tags: java

So I am having trouble repeating my text 3 times, reversing the sentence and counting the letters's in the word. Can someone please help me out? I have tried googling and looking for a method and cannot seem to get any of them to work. It would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Please give proper title to your question.

Comment: You're struggling with all three tasks?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about checking the code in question.  It might be more suited to http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: [tag:javascript] tag removed. FYI, please read on the differences between Java and JavaScript because they are significant. Why is this important? If you use the wrong tag, you attract the wrong experts to your question which doesn't help you get decent answers, and frustrates the helpers.

Comment: Yes, I have written the other parts of my code, but have erased them here because I don't need help on those parts.

Comment: Should the repeat text be in some kind of loop?  You're returning `text` from your `reverseLetters` rather then `reverse` and your appending the text to it...

Comment: Please improve your question by first and foremost, ***asking*** a question. All you've done so far is post what you want and then dump your code, which isn't a real question. Putting a little effort into your question will go a long way towards getting a decent and quick answer.

Comment: What exactly is your error, what is your expected input, current output and expected output?

Comment: What are you trying to do in your if-statement inside the `reverseLetters` function?

Comment: Why on earth did you delete all your code from the question?  This makes a complete mockery of the question.  Stack Overflow is not just for your benefit - it is so that other people can look for questions and answers that match their own issues.  Please put the code back into your question.

Answer (score 1):

You have a misplaced semi-colon at the end of your if-statement meaning that the statement after it will always be executed.

```
if(text.charAt(i) == 'e'); // Remove the last character here
{
    System.out.println("e :" + text.charAt(i) + i);
    count++;
}
```

---

As for your `reverseLetters` function, I don't know if the `return text;` outside of your for loop can be reached but you're overwriting the value of `reverse` on each iteration. I think what you should be trying instead is to append the value of `text.charAt(j)` to the value of `reverse` like so:

```
String reverse = ""; // Must be initialised to an empty string
for(int j = text.length()-1; j >= 0; j--)
{
    reverse += text.charAt(j);
    /* The rest of the contents of your loop here */
```

---

And what do you expect your `repeatLetters` function to do? You're assigning the given String to a local variable named `repeat` and then you're just returning that value without doing anything. You could use a loop to append `text` to an empty String three times and return that.

```
String repeat = "";
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    repeat += text + " ";
}
return repeat;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I removed the ; and that is working now. Sometimes things are so simple and yet I miss them!

Comment: I also changed the repeat to the following, however, it still would not repeat the text 3 times. String repeat = " ";
 for (int r=0; r<3; r++)
 {
   repeat += text + " ";
 }
 return repeat;
}

Comment: @user3290671: I can't replicate that that result. Could you please paste your code in your original post?